# WxPython's ScrolledWindow element collapses to minimum size

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am using a Panel within a Frame to display images (the GUI need to switch between multiple panels and hence the hierarchy). As images should be displayed in native size I used ScrolledWindow as the panel parent. The scrolls do appear and work, but it causes the Panel to collapse to minimum size and it needs to be resized using drag&drop every time. 
Is there a way around this?

Below is a reduced version of the code, which shows the problem:

```
import os
import wx
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub


class Edit_Panel(wx.PyScrolledWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Edit_Panel, self).__init__(parent)

        # Display size
        width, height = wx.DisplaySize()
        self.photoMaxSize = height - 500

        # Loaded image
        self.loaded_image = None

        # Icons
        self.open_icon_id = 500

        # Generate panel
        self.layout()

    def layout(self):
        self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        divider = wx.StaticLine(self, -1, style = wx.LI_HORIZONTAL)
        self.main_sizer.Add(divider, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)

        self.toolbar = self.init_toolbar()
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.toolbar, 0, wx.ALL)

        img = wx.EmptyImage(self.photoMaxSize, self.photoMaxSize)
        self.image_control = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY,
                                             wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.image_control, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)

        self.image_label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, style = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.image_label, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, 5)

        self.SetSizer(self.main_sizer)

        fontsz = wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT).GetPixelSize()
        self.SetScrollRate(fontsz.x, fontsz.y)
        self.EnableScrolling(True, True)

    def init_toolbar(self):
        toolbar = wx.ToolBar(self)
        toolbar.SetToolBitmapSize((16, 16))

        open_ico = wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_FILE_OPEN, wx.ART_TOOLBAR, (16, 16))
        open_tool = toolbar.AddSimpleTool(self.open_icon_id, open_ico, "Open", "Open an Image Directory")
        handler = self.on_open_reference
        self.Bind(event = wx.EVT_MENU, handler = handler, source = open_tool)

        toolbar.Realize()

        return toolbar

    def on_open_reference(self, event, wildcard = None):
        if wildcard is None:
            wildcard = self.get_wildcard()

        defaultDir = '~/'
        dbox = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose an image to display", defaultDir = defaultDir, wildcard = wildcard, style = wx.OPEN)

        if dbox.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            file_name = dbox.GetPath()

            # load image
            self.load_image(image = file_name)

        dbox.Destroy()

    def get_wildcard(self):
        wildcard = 'Image files (*.jpg;*.png;*.bmp)|*.png;*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpeg'
        return wildcard

    def load_image(self, image):
        self.loaded_image = image

        # Load image
        img = wx.Image(image, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)

        # Label image name
        image_name = os.path.basename(image)
        self.image_label.SetLabel(image_name)

        # scale the image, preserving the aspect ratio
        scale_image = True
        if scale_image:
            W = img.GetWidth()
            H = img.GetHeight()
            if W > H:
                NewW = self.photoMaxSize
                NewH = self.photoMaxSize * H / W
            else:
                NewH = self.photoMaxSize
                NewW = self.photoMaxSize * W / H
            img = img.Scale(NewW, NewH)

        self.image_control.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img))

        # Render
        self.main_sizer.Layout()

        self.main_sizer.Fit(self)
        self.Refresh()

        pub.sendMessage("resize", msg = "")


class Viewer_Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        super(Viewer_Frame, self).__init__(parent = parent, id = id, title = title)

        # Edit panel
        self.edit_panel = Edit_Panel(self)

        # Default panel
        self.main_panel = self.edit_panel

        # Render frame
        self.render_frame()

        # Subscription to re-render
        pub.subscribe(self.resize_frame, ("resize"))

    def render_frame(self):
        # Main Sizer
        self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # Add default sizer
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.main_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        # Render
        self.SetSizer(self.main_sizer)
        self.Show()
        self.main_sizer.Fit(self)
        self.Center()


    def resize_frame(self, msg):
        self.main_sizer.Fit(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Viewer_Frame(parent = None, id = -1, title = 'Toolkit')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: If i get you correctly, this is not a problem. Since you are using sizers to fit the containing elements, it is doing its best and shrinking everything to occupy the minimum amount of space. When your frame is displayed, it does not have any component in it that would fill space, that is why it collapses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `Fit()`, so you're explicitly asking the panel to fit its contents, but you don't specify the min/best size of this contents anywhere (AFAICS, there is a lot of code here, so I could be missing something).

If you want to use some minimal size for the panel, just set it using `SetMinSize()`.